# Is possible to handle captcha in selenium, if the captcha is a static one?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

My code:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "****************");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("**************");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[text()='Create A Profile']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("..//div[@class='captcha-input']/input[@id='Module-Captcha-Captcha-input-78189cbe4512de369a72d22c7050fbec0ea3f5cb86f351bafbb344df0f04508deebb23aa6f910098a68acaace3eb00ab' ]")).sendKeys("000");

  }

}
```

The html

```
<div class="captcha-input"> 
    <label class="form-label block required" for="Module-Captcha-Captcha-input-78189cbe4512de369a72d22c7050fbec0ea3f5cb86f351bafbb344df0f04508deebb23aa6f910098a68acaace3eb00ab"> 
    <input id="Module-Captcha-Captcha-input-78189cbe4512de369a72d22c7050fbec0ea3f5cb86f351bafbb344df0f04508deebb23aa6f910098a68acaace3eb00ab" class="full-width narrow Component-Form-Validation-Validation field" name="captcha.captchaSolution" data-validation-error="" data-validation-message="Please enter the correct captcha " aria-required="true" required="required" type="text"/> 
</div>
```

I get the error `no such element: Unable to locate element` on the last code statement.

Comment: What do you mean? If captcha does not change then you know what value should you input. So you do not need to parse an image.

Comment: @AlexeyR. For the testing environment the developers has create the static captch as feature in order to bypass this

Comment: Welcome to SQA. Please update the title, the problem is not specific to captcha.

Comment: I have edited your question to add the information in the comments. Next time you need to add information, please edit the question instead of placing critical information in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: Is the id for the input field every time the same? It looks like something that will be different every time. Then it will be beter to use name instead of id.

Comment: *Thanks all for the response* It is working fine when I'm using **following-sibling** in the Xpath and **JavaScript** for entering text into text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `..` from the start of your xpath expression. Double dot is used for relative look up. However you do not need that since you have no elements to relatively move from. Your lookup should be absolute.

So the code would look like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Create A Profile']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='captcha-input']/input[@id='Module-Captcha-Captcha-input-78189cbe4512de369a72d22c7050fbec0ea3f5cb86f351bafbb344df0f04508deebb23aa6f910098a68acaace3eb00ab' ]")).sendKeys("000");
```